# Mail is successfully sent but not received

Tags: php

I am working on a project in which i have to send mails to users etc. My mails are being successfully sent but i cannot see the mails in my account. I donot have any hosting website is it important to have any hosting website for getting mails in the account. I am currently using smtp4dev which shows me that my mail has been sent. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from the homepage of smtp4dev: (https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/)

> **Project Description**
>
> Windows 7/Vista/XP/2003/2010 compatible dummy SMTP server. Sits in the system tray and does not deliver the received messages. The received messages can be quickly viewed, saved and the source/structure inspected. Useful for testing/debugging software that generates email.

That means it will not send emails. Dummy smtp servers comes in very handy while development but to see actual emails you need real ones.

Comment: Do you have any idea what can i do

Comment: You can install a real SMTP server to your computer. That way you would see emails. As an alternative, you may use your gmail account to send emails. It would not allow to change FROM address but it will allow to send actual emails.

Answer (score 0):

mail.Headers.Add("Message-Id",String.Format("<{0}@{1}>",     Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "mail.example.com"));

I fixed this issue in C# with adding header in mail message.